# cakephp timeHelper isToday

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I am using cakePHP time format to change a date to the users timezone. Then I wish to check if it is today. When I pass $currentDate into $this->Time->isToday I get nothing back, even thought it is todays date.

If I pass in date("d/m/Y"); it works fine.

I have tried stringToTime also.

```
$currentDate = $this->Time->format(
                'd/m/Y',
                $message['Message']['created'],
                null,
                $userData['time_zone']
);

if($this->Time->isToday($currentDate)){
    echo "today";
};
```

This is the fix I have implemented.

```
if($this->Time->isToday($message['Message']['created'], $userData['time_zone'])){
    echo '<li class="conversation-divider"><span>Conversation started Toady</span></li>';
} else {
    echo '<li class="conversation-divider"><span>Conversation started at '.$messageDate.'</span></li>';
};
```

Comment: Did you make the timezone helper aware of the timezone you used in format()? I guess that is your problem.

Comment: sorry I have never seen a mention of setting up timezone helper. I am echoing $currentDate and it displays fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the CakePHP book, you can pass timezone to the 'isToday()' method:

```
TimeHelper::isToday($dateString, $timezone = NULL)
```

So - try this:

```
$today = $this->Time->isToday(
    $message['Message']['created'],
    $userData['time_zone']
);
```

Comment: thank you. Now that I can pass the users timezone in with the raw date I can use it now. That was why I was using the format before, which the result did not work with isToday.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the timezone helper aware of the timezone you used in format()?
You need to at least once set timezone($timezone) for it to know it.

See https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.php#L272